# Mongoose - E11000 duplicate key error collection?? Only happens after I create first user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jwt

This is really frustrating because this wasn't happening yesterday until I started adding stuff for jwt today. I can sign up a new user JUST FINE. When I go to create a second user, I get this weird E11000 duplicate key message. Here is the error:

```
name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: roomtrack.users index: roommates._id_1 dup key: { : null }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 0,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: roomtrack.users index: roommates._id_1 dup key: { : null }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

Here is my user create controller, which was working PERFECTLY FINE yesterday. Suddenly I wake up and have problems?:

```
create: function(req, res) {
    User.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
      password: req.body.password
    }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(user);
      }

   })
```

And finally, my user model/schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a username"],
    minlength: [6, "Username must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [15, "Username cannot exceed 15 characters"],
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
    minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"],
    maxlength: [17, "Password cannot exceed 17 characters"],
  },
  roommates: [
    {
      roommates: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}, 
      status: {type: String, default: "pending"}, 
      requests: [
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Request"}
      ],
      balance: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: In your model you have an unique Index on the `username` field. If you try to add a new user with the same *username*, MongoDB will complain. What is the output of `getIndexes()`?

Comment: It seems to be working fine now even with the unique Index validator. I honestly have NO idea what was going on here. Ghost in the system. I commented out about 5 things in different controllers, and re commented them one by one, testing the login with each new recomment, and suddenly, everything was working when they were all back to normal from their uncommented state. Always happens when you hone in on the problem and you KNOW nothing's wrong. The computer stops bluffing :) lol